# AngularJs animate background color / colour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, colors, jquery-animate, directive

I have been trying to Dynamically Animate a background between 2 colours on click using AngularJs Directives and Controllers (with no success so far).

Does anyone know how to do this?
I have been trying to store the currCol (stored as an array var pushed into ng-class), but then I can not retrieve the value from ng-class and use it.

I have css transitioned from clear to the colour, but I cannot figure out how to get the transition between 2 dynamic colour vars. 
Any help will be great. Thanks.

Some code so far:

index.html

```
    <body ng-app="colourTest">
        <div ng-controller="BgCtrl" >
            <ion-nav-bar id="bgCont" data-mylo-color="" ng-class="colorVal" animate-On-Change="colorVal" ></ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
                 <button ng-click="test3()">set bg</button>           
            </ion-nav-view>
        </div>
    </body>
```

controllers.js

```
.controller('BgCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.colorPane = 'whiteBg';
    $scope.colorVal = '';
    var colCount = 0;
    var colorArr = ['redBg', 'greenBg', 'blueBg', 'whiteBg'];
    var currColor = '';       

    $scope.test3 = function () {         
        if (colCount < colorArr.length)
        {
            $scope.colorVal = colorArr[colCount];            
            colCount ++;    
        } else {
            colCount = 0;
            $scope.colorVal = colorArr[colCount];
        }
    }
}])
```

.directives.js

```
.directive('animateOnChange', ['$animate', function($animate) {  

  return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    //var container = angular.element(document.querySelector('#bgCont') );    
    //var currCol = container[0].attributes[1];
    scope.$watch(attrs.animateOnChange, function (nv, ov) {

        //var colVar = attrs.ngClass;
        //colVar = nv;        
    });
  };  
}]);
```

app.css

```
.greenBg {
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.redBg {
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: When you press the button you want it to transition to the next color in the array, and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a directive for that, just use [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) animation hooks.

```
.greenBg-add, .greenBg-remove,
.redBg-add, .redBg-remove,
.blueBg-add, .blueBg-remove,
.whiteBg-add, .whiteBg-remove {
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.greenBg,
.greenBg-add.greenBg-add-active {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.redBg,
.redBg-add.redBg-add-active {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.blueBg,
.blueBg-add.blueBg-add-active {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.whiteBg,
.whiteBg-add.whiteBg-add-active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RUUPZDPuPZ6nutgE0DZJ?p=preview)

Comment: That is much simpler, I was making it too complicated trying to use a directive. This idea worked great.